# Semi-synchronous master master replication

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication, database-backups, multiple-databases

I am building a "Semi-synchronous master master replication". There are two databases in two different servers. People on both sides can read/write from/into these two databases.

Servers (A & B), with MySQL Enterprise Edition 5.6 version. I want to replicate database records from Server A to Server B. In same time i want Server B database records to replicate to Server A.

For example if server A database have a table **Products** with 1000 records and server B database have table **Products** with 950 records then database A replicate remaining 50 records in database B.

and

same goes for server B 
if server B database have a table **Products** with 1050 records and server A database have table **Products** with 1000 records then database B replicate remaining 50 records in database A.

I am new to db replication have no idea is it possible or not with "Semi-synchronous master master replication"